# Drive MFC Application from Win32 Console Application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I have a situation where I need to essentially run some unit tests against a MFC application.

I basically have some gtest code in Win32 Console application that needs to be able to create a instance in code of the MFC application and basically do some assertions etc...

I tried to create a Win32 console application with MFC header included. I then included the header file of my MFC applicaton class. However, whenever I try to create an instance i.e  `CWindowApplicationApp the_app` in my console application, I receive linking error

This is some of the source code from my console application

```
CWindowApplicationApp the_app;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
int nRetCode = 0;

// initialize MFC and print and error on failure
if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
{
    // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
    _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
    nRetCode = 1;
}
else
{

}

return nRetCode;
}
```

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CWindowApplicationApp::CWindowApplicationApp(void)" (??0CWindowApplicationApp@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'the_app''(void)" (??__Ethe_app@@YAXXZ)

Any help? I have included the header file paths

Answer (score 0):

The linker is telling you it doesn't know where to find the object code for CWindowApplicationApp's constructor.

You need to link with whatever object files define `CWindowApplicationApp` (typically WindowApplicationApp.obj), as well as any other object files that are referred to by WindowApplicationApp.obj (very dependent on your app structure).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong road. It is not possible to create an instance of an application inside another application. What will work is to add some test code into the application and rebuild it.